# Android: not optimal Image load

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I got this little function that allows me to load an image from a `path`, named `name`. It works, the problem is that I have to call this many times, una tantum. Let's say, a dozen of times at the load of a specific activity. It takes few seconds to load them all.

Is it optimal? Is there a lighter way to achieve the same result?

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFrom(File path, String name)
    {
        try {
            File f = new File(path, name);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried adding `if(!f.exists()) return null;` like this:

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFrom(File path, String name)
    {
        try {
            File f = new File(path, name);
            if(!f.exists()) return null;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I know that is redundant, but I can't remove the Try Catch clause, cause it giving me an error if I do. However, no speed up noticed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that your code is inefficient, as far as I know, loading pictures manually on the main thread *will* hurt your app's performance. Especially when you have a large amount of pictures and/or using them to populate your `ListView` or `GridView`.

Have a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), these libraries should help load your pictures efficiently thus speeding up your app.